# Tomcat sends 400s before processing android requests with an authentication header

Tags: java, android, tomcat, bad-request

I am writing a basic android app for sending and receiving messages. I am also writing the server side code using Tomcat 7.0.21. I am currently trying to implement "programmatic web application security" (http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html), where client authentication is performed explicitly.

I have now finished this implementation, and it works fine when I send a request using a REST client. However, when I send the request from an Android device/simulator, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException. When I check the tomcat access logs, it seems tomcat is sending a 400 Bad Request before my Servlet code is even executed, thus producing the exception.

I don't know whether this problem is client side or server side. Any insight or suggestions on how else to implement this would be greatly appeciated. Thank you.

Tomcat localhost_access_log:

```
192.168.1.2 - - [05/Dec/2012:12:20:39 +0100] "GET /CA/users/get_contacts?user_id=freespirit HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Servlet classes I extend, which I believe are never executed:

```
package carter.server.conversations;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import carter.sqlite.SQLiteUtilities;
import carter.sqlite.conversations.DatabaseHelper;

public class AuthorizationServlet extends HttpsServlet {

    protected static final int SERVLET_EXCEPTION_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        super.doGet(request, response);

        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(authorization == null){
            System.out.println("CAAuthorizationServlet: Authorization is null. Sending 401.");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        else{
            String base64encodedDetails = authorization.substring(6).trim(); //remove "BASIC " prefix
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            String unencodedDetails = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(base64encodedDetails));
            String[] userDetails = unencodedDetails.split(":");
            //check database for given details
            Connection databaseConnection = SQLiteUtilities.getConnection(Constants.databasePath);
            try{
                String password = DatabaseHelper.getPassword(userDetails[0], databaseConnection);
                if(password.equals(userDetails[1]) == false){
                    //password does not match this user
                    System.out.println("CAAuthorizationServlet: password does not match this user. Sending 401.");
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                // no such user found in database.
                System.out.println("CAAuthorizationServlet: no such user exists in database. Sending 401.");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            finally{
                SQLiteUtilities.closeConnection(databaseConnection);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        super.doPost(request, response);
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}


package carter.server.conversations;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HttpsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("CAHttpsServlet: checking request is secure");
        if(request.isSecure() == false){
            System.out.println("CAHttpsServlet: Request is NOT secure. Sending 400");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, you are rejecting the request in your own code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("CAHttpsServlet: checking request is secure");
    if(request.isSecure() == false){
        System.out.println("CAHttpsServlet: Request is NOT secure. Sending 400");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: I commented out the `sendError` line and still no luck. I never see the preceding log message either.

Comment: Are you checking your catalina.out log file?

Comment: I'm using eclipse so Catalina.out logging is seen in the console (I'm not 100% sure on this so please correct me if I'm wrong). This sample is taken directly after reloading:  `06-Dec-2012 16:45:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/CA] is completed
carter.server.conversations.SignIn      | Secure request: true
user freespirit with password sweetypie trying to sign in
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /tmp/sqlite-3.7.2-libsqlitejdbc.so already loaded in another classloader
Successful sign in`

Comment: The sign in request is sent and is successful. The user is then taken to another Activity which immediately send a request to get their contacts, containing the Authorization header. There are no further logs seen here, despite the fact the relevant servlet has a log in the first line of `doGet()`. All I can see are the logs from `localhost_access_log.2012-12-06.txt`:  
`192.168.1.2 - - [06/Dec/2012:16:48:31 +0100] "POST /CA/users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 200 110  
192.168.1.2 - - [06/Dec/2012:16:48:32 +0100] "GET /CA/users/get_contacts?user_id=freespirit HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Comment: That would indicate that there is a problem in the servlet implementing the 'Get Contact' functionality. You might want to put some additional logging in it.

Comment: You're right. I put two extra log messages in the init() methods of both servlets involved. Upon signing in, I see the sign in request go through fine, but the get contacts servlet still didn't log _anything_. This lead me to believe it was a problem client side. After hours of tinkering, I got it to work by using  
`String authorization = UserPreferences.getAuthorization(this);  
authorization = authorization.substring(0,authorization.length()-1);  
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",authorization);`

Here, urlConnection is a HttpURLConnection.
`

Comment: Why on earth this works, I have no idea. But after so long trying to solve it, I'm happy.  
That said, I will be very grateful if anyone could explain it to me!

Comment: Could be some extra characters are getting padded on to your authorization string. What happens if you do this `System.out.printf("Authorization header: '%s'\n", UserPreferences.getAuthorization(this));`?

Comment: `Authorization header: 'BASIC ZnJlZXNwaXJpdDpzd2VldHlwaWU=`  
`Authorization header: 'BASIC ZnJlZXNwaXJpdDpzd2VldHlwaWU='`  

I see now. The end index of the substring method is exclusive so I was actually removing the last character of the string. I wasn't aware of this before. It turned out to be a LF character, added after using `android.util.Base64.encodeToString()`.  
Tomcat must automatically reject authentication headers formatted in this way, although I haven't found any documentation that reflects this.  
Thanks for helping me through it Perception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's related with the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You'll need to enable cross-domain requests on your Tomcat server.

For this, you'll need to create a `crossdomain.xml` file on the ROOT webapp of your Tomcat, with a content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I copied the file exactly as you have given it into ROOT webapp but unfortunately this did not work. I'm not sure if this is the problem though. All my code is located in the same webapp and all requests are made on port 8443.

Comment: Once you have set up this file, can you access it via `https://host:8443/crossdomain.xml`?